# CatBoost Machine Learning hyperparameters: why not always use `thread_count = -1`?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, hyperparameters, catboost

With respect specifically to CatBoost:

1. Under what scenarios might one want to use fewer than the max number of threads of one's CPU? I cannot find an answer to this.
2. Is there a fixed cost/overhead associated with each core utilized? I.e., is more always better for all data set types/sizes?

Do the answers to the questions above generalize to all machine learning algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

I think that most of the reasons for changing the `thread_count` are not catboost specific. Other libraries like sklearn offer the same feature. Reasons for not running with all CPUs are:

- Debugging: If there is a problem it might be handy to only have one thread thus making the process more simple.
- You want other processes on your machine to have CPU power. Especially if you have a server for in-memory data analysis shared by a team of data scientists. Your colleagues won't be happy if you take all resources.
- Your job is so small that it simply does not need all the resources.
- Your parallelize in another way: For example you try different hyper parameters using cross validation. Then it would make sense to dedicate one CPU to training one model rather than training a model with with all CPUs and then move on to train the next model with all CPUs

I hope this answers question 1. This generalizes to other in-memory ml libraries like sklearn.

Regarding question 2 I'm not sure. CatBoost does the parallelisation somewhere in its C++ Code and uses it via Cython in the Python package. I assume it introduces some overhead (since distributed computing always introduces overhead) but it's probably not too much. You could find out by timing some experiments.

Comment: Thank you. These are good points and some were ones I had not thought of. Looking to crowdsource more explanations before accepting an answer. Thanks for taking the time